# BootstrapDialog and angularJS including html

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-dialog

I am using https://github.com/nakupanda/bootstrap3-dialog to show dialogs on my webapp.

```
$scope.importFileWithSettings = function(){
                BootstrapDialog.show({
                        type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_INFO,
                        message: "<div ng-include=\"'importform.html'\"></div>",
                        title: 'Title',
                });
            };
```

importform.html is in the same directory. When the dialog shows it does not show importform.html content. How to do it right (I am relatively new to angularJS and bootsrap)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use script component of angularjs it is best way to include templates...

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="exampleTemplateId">
   Content of the template.
</script>
```

then in you `ng-include` directive use it with its id

```
<div ng-include=\"'exampleTemplateId'\"></div>
```

for more details you can check [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script)

**UPDATE**

You can use [$templateCache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache) service of angularjs for this purpose...

in your `run` block you can use this service like this

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.run(function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put('exampleTemplateId', 'This is the content of the template');
});
```

and again use it in `ng-inlucde` as I stated above

Comment: But I have to place <script>...</script> in line in order to run it. Is it possible to place it in external file?

Comment: @MarcinMajewski u can use $templateCache service in your run config... let me add it on to answer...

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation this should work:

```
$scope.importFileWithSettings = function(){
    BootstrapDialog.show({
            type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_INFO,
            message: "$('<div></div>').load('importform.html')",
            title: 'Title',
    });
};
```

Comment: I am getting error because it is trying to get "myhost:port/importform.html", but not the html that is in the same directory as script.